# Is there a way for googletest to generate caller line numbers for asserts in a called function?

Tags: c++, c++14, googletest

I am writing some unit tests in a C++14 project where I often want to check a large number of invariants.  The natural way to do this is to create a method:

```
void validateState(const Model& model, int offset) {
    ASSERT_EQ(model.ax * model.bx, model.cx * offset);
    ASSERT_NE(model.base, offset);
    ...
}
```

The problem is if these asserts fail, I get the line number of the method.  Is there a way to get googletest to print the line number of the caller, and the specific assert that failed?

Comment: Don't know of builtin option to print what you ask for automatically, but you can stream messages to assertion macros. e.g. `EXPECT_TRUE(false) << "some message";` This allows you to add a unique message for the specific assert that failed.

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/1621 tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a built-in way: SCOPED_TRACE (see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#using-assertions-in-sub-routines) does exactly what you want.